# How do I avoid typos in a resume?

Tags: resume

My resume accidentally had a typo in the name of one of the schools I attended. The school is [County Name] Technical Community College. I had accidentally listed it as [County Name] County Community College. I don't know why I missed it, except for the fact that I'm often working on these late at night. I have lots of different resumes for different positions, but they all have this error because they tend to be copied from the same basic format. Is there any way I can avoid mistakes like this in the future? Is this likely to have been the reason I didn't get any of the jobs I interviewed for, or is that just idle speculation? Thanks.

Comment: "And is this likely to have been the reason I didn't get any of the jobs I interviewed for, or is that just idle speculation?" For all we know, there are several other glaring mistakes that you haven't caught yet. You need to show this resume to all your professional friends.

Comment: This would only be a serious issue if there is another unrelated college with the name you actually put.

Comment: That's not a typo. A typo is a physical mistyping (hence "**typ**o") of the intended character sequence. Using the wrong word (but spelling it correctly as intended) is not a typo, that's just a plain mistake.

Answer (score 5):

1. Proofread. Have a friend proofread. Proofread again. Old professional trick: proofread from the last word backwards so your expectations don't cause you to skim past things you don't expect to have gotten wrong.

Spill chuckers carrot ketch Avery mist ache. The -- sorry, typo, "they" -- help, but don't rely on them when meaning matters.

2. Yes, that's pure speculation. "Technical" might have gotten more attention, or might not. All you can do is say "oops", correct it, and keep applying.

You could *try* reapplying with a cover letter explaining that you caught this error and, if it might have made a difference, you'd appreciate reconsideration. It won't hurt. It probably won't help.

Comment: I am not sure it’s worth the squeeze. I am not even sure will care about the name of the school an AA was earned, only it was warned, such a small typo is hardly worth pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

In the bigger picture, no one really cares about this sort of thing at the interview stage unless they can look there and instantly determine that you've made a blatant lie about your education (i.e. you attended "University of Toys'R'Us").  Also, work experience trumps education unless you are very early in your career.

The only place a typo might cause a problem is when a company decides to hire you and check your credentials during a background check.  At that stage, a typo might mean the background check company can't find what you've indicated. You might have to give the background check company the correct name, but it would just make the process longer and probably not reflect on you poorly because of a typo.

Comment: Typographical errors in a resume are easily avoided, depending on the amount of typographical errors, one could classify the errors existing in such an easily written document to be a sign attention to details are not important to the individual. In this specific example, the single duplication of a word, wouldn’t be important enough to warrant rejection of a candidate.  Although attention to details are important, essential in a document, which entire purpose is to promote positive qualities not negative quality of yourself as a candidate